# How is the output of `losetup --list` sorted?

Tags: mount, util-linux

When I run `losetup --list` (or just `losetup`) to get a list of the loopback devices on my system, the output doesn't seem to be in any meaningful order:

```
0 $  losetup --list
NAME        SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE                                                   DIO LOG-SEC
/dev/loop1          0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1885.snap                         0     512
/dev/loop29         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1880.snap                         0     512
/dev/loop19         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1506.snap              0     512
/dev/loop27         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-characters_539.snap                0     512
/dev/loop17         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-characters_550.snap                0     512
/dev/loop8          0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1502.snap              0     512
/dev/loop25         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18_4.snap   0     512
/dev/loop15         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/glimpse-editor_134.snap                  0     512
/dev/loop6          0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-calculator_730.snap                0     512
/dev/loop23         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-logs_93.snap                       0     512
/dev/loop13         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/wormhole_112.snap                        0     512
/dev/loop4          0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/canonical-livepatch_94.snap              0     512
```

It's clearly not sorted by the name of the device, nor the name of the backing file. Is the order just arbitrary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`losetup` reads [`getdents64()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents64.2.html) from `/sys/block`, so it's the order of entries in that directory.

If you get the same order with `ls -f` (do not sort), then that's it:

```
# ls -f /sys/block | grep loop
loop1
loop6
loop4
loop2
loop0
loop7
loop5
loop3
```

And `losetup` to compare:

```
# losetup
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE  DIO LOG-SEC
/dev/loop1         0      0         0  0 /dev/shm/b   0     512
/dev/loop6         0      0         0  0 /dev/shm/c   0     512
/dev/loop4         0      0         0  0 /dev/shm/a   0     512
/dev/loop2         0      0         0  0 /dev/shm/c   0     512
/dev/loop0         0      0         0  0 /dev/shm/a   0     512
/dev/loop7         0      0         0  0 /dev/shm/d   0     512
/dev/loop5         0      0         0  0 /dev/shm/b   0     512
/dev/loop3         0      0         0  0 /dev/shm/d   0     512
```

---

The `getdents` manpage mentions nothing regarding order, but [`readdir`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) says:

```
   The order in which filenames are read by successive calls to readdir()
   depends on the filesystem implementation; it is unlikely that the names
   will be sorted in any fashion.
```

Programs that output files in a sorted list (`ls` etc.) usually sort it themselves, and when you use things like `echo *`, the shell is doing the sorting for you.

For `losetup` output, I guess no one bothered to sort it in any meaningful way.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, edited the answer